# Reading UTF-8 data from MySQL shows ? instead of ı

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Here is how I read the data:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$number = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `mystory` where `id` = ' . "$number" . ' LIMIT 1');

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['story'];
?>
```

The data is encoded as utf8_bin.
Insted of **ı** PHP outputs **?**

Why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to make sure that your connection to the database us in UTF-8 as well. You can do that this way:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Also make sure that you are telling the browser that it is UTF-8:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the only code worked for me :-

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
```

Where $con is your connection value to DB .
Be sure put the code after connect and error code and you will be fine .

Answer (score 0):

I am use all this operations:

```
mysql_query ('SET NAMES utf8');
mysql_query ('SET CHARACTER utf8');
mysql_set_charset ('utf8', $LINK);
```